# iOS share extension hiding on number of items selected

Tags: ios, swift

I see that app like twitter has the feature to automatically hide the share extension depending on number of items selected, .ie in Photo app like:

[image]

[image]

Anybody has any idea on how to obtain something like twitter share extension

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting  **NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount** in info.plist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use: Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html